# Python | Telegram bot, Проблемы с запуском?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Помогите пожалуйста, при запуске бота появляются куча ошибок:

```
$ D:\pythonу\telegrambot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonу\telegrambot.py", line 34, in <module>
    bot.polling( none_stop = True )
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 664, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 726, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 686, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\pythonу\telegrambot.py", line 15, in send_echo
    answer = "В городе " + str(message.text) + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status() + "\n"
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `w.detailed_status` попробуйте так

Comment: Не помогло, всё равно те же ошибки

Comment: По ошибке записан один код,, на картинке в это же строке другой код.

Comment: Я немного не понял

Comment: type detailed_status: Unicode Из документаций. Значит надо преобравать str(w.detailed_status)

Comment: Спасибо, хороший человек))

Comment: – 
Pavlic приведенный код не соответствует ошибке

Comment: Это может быть Subline text не правильно работает